How to calculate this definite-Integral? Is it possible to use residue theorem?
I'm seeking assistance with the following integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1 + cx\right)^{a}\,
\left(1 + dx\right)^{b}\,}\,{\rm d}x\quad\mbox{where}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
{\displaystyle a} & {\displaystyle >} & {\displaystyle 1}
\\
{\displaystyle b} & {\displaystyle >} & {\displaystyle 2}
\\
{\displaystyle c} & {\displaystyle >} & {\displaystyle 0}
\\
{\displaystyle d} & {\displaystyle >} & {\displaystyle 0}
\end{array}\right.
$$

I attempted to compute it using
$\tt Wolfram\ Mathematica$, but the result was expressed in terms of the Hypergeometric $_{2}\!\operatorname{F}_{1}$ function.
Unfortunately, when I evaluated it for specific numerical values, the result returned was 'ComplexInfinity'.
As a result, the $\tt Mathematica$ output is not providing a viable solution.

Any insights or alternative approaches to evaluate this integral would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance !.

Have you considered partial fractions?

Are the powers $a$ and $b$ real or integer?

Can you check in the mathematica ouput, that when you simplify by putting parameters $c=d$, you get the result $$ \frac{1}{(b+a-1)c}$$

The hypergeometric result comes this integral representation.

I don't think a closed form exists, the best we can do is to represent it as a ${}_2F_1$ Hypergeom function. I think the above integral can be written as $$\frac{c^{b-1}}{(a+b-1)d^b}{}_2F_1\left(b,a+b-1;a+b;1-\frac{c}{d}\right)$$

Dear Sam, I want to express my gratitude for your helpful response. Your solution proved effective, yielding accurate results for various values of a, b, c, and d. Could you please provide guidance on how to derive the solution you provided? Additionally, I'm curious whether a similar result can be obtained if the function in the denominator is of the form $(f+cx)^a$, instead of $(1+cx)^a$?, i.e., the function is $\frac{1}{(f+cx)^a (1+dx)^b}$, where $f$ is a positive real number. Thank you so much for your valuable help.

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{(f+c x)^a (g+d x)^b} , dx=\frac{f^{-a} g^{1-b} , 2F_1\left(1,a;a+b;1-\frac{c g}{d f}\right)}{(-1+a+b) d}=\frac{f^{1-a} g^{-b}
\left(\frac{c g}{d f}\right)^b \left(1-\frac{c g}{d f}\right)^{1-a-b} B{1-\frac{c g}{d f}}(-1+a+b,1-b)}{c}$$ where: $B_z(a,b)$ is  incomplete beta function.

Dear Mariusz, thank you so much. Could you help me with some intermediate steps to obtain the final result?

Consider the integral $$I = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(f+c\cdot x)^{a}(1+d\cdot x)^b}$$ where $a,b,c,d,f$ are positive constants as written in the problem.Before I begin, denote $(a)_n = \frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma(a)}$ as the Pochhammer symbol of $a$ where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function, and $$ {}_2F_{1}(a,b,c,z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n (b)_n}{(c)_n} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$ Additionally, $\frac{1}{n+z} = \frac{(z)_n}{z(z+1)_n}$ and $$ \left(1+\alpha t\right)^{-a} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n}{n!}\left(-\alpha t\right)^n. $$ This follows from the Binomial expansion. Now do the change of variables $1+d\cdot x= \frac{1}{t}$ in I, for $x=0 \mapsto t=1$ and $x\to \infty$ implies $t \to 0$. This results in the Jacobian $-1/(d\cdot t^2)$, and the integral now can be simplified as
$$\begin{align*} 
I &= \frac{1}{d}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{b-2}}{\left(f+\frac{c}{d}\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)\right)^a}dt = d^{a-1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{b+a-2}}{\left(c+(fd-c)t\right)^a}dt,\\
&= \frac{d^{a-1}}{c^{a}}\int_{0}^{1} t^{b+a-2}\left(1+\frac{fd-c}{c}t\right)^{-a}dt
\end{align*}$$
Using the Binomial expansion written above, $$\begin{align*} I &=  \frac{d^{a-1}}{c^{a}}\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n}{n!}\left(1-\frac{fd}{c}\right)^{n}t^{n+a+b-2}dt \\
&=\frac{d^{a-1}}{(a+b-1)c^{a}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n(a+b-1)_n}{(a+b)_n}\frac{1}{n!}\left(1-\frac{fd}{c}\right)^{n}\end{align*}$$
Thus, $$\boxed{I = \frac{d^{a-1}}{(a+b-1)c^{a}}{}_2F_1\left(a,a+b-1;a+b;1-\frac{fd}{c}\right)}$$
Edit 1: This might seem different from the solution written in the comment for $f=1$. But using Pfaff transformation (see here), the solutions are same since $$ { }_2 F_1(a, b ; c ; z)=(1-z)^{-b}{ }_2 F_1\left(c-a, b; c ; \frac{z}{z-1}\right).$$
